# Help identifying PJ2089 DZK

Tags: diodes, identification, components

I'm trying to identify a component with the designation PJ2089 DZK. The PCB has a "Z" next to it, so I looked around for Zeners. However, the closest thing to this reference was a 1N2089 diode. At this point I'm not even sure it's a diode as the cathode bar cannot be determined.

[image]

Comment: This is the only meaningful reference I found:  https://www.yoycart.com/Product/544598096794/

It may be a proprietary or limited market product.  I'd spend some time tracing out the circuit to try to find out what its function might be on the board.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for for the lookup. These components will connect to a relay that is rated at 24VDC. However, it does not close contacts properly as only about 7.5VDC are present. They seemed the most logical source of the issue as the relay closes properly when energized at 24VDC.

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**: I suspect it's a Panjit 8.55V bi-directional TVS diode - see page 2 on this [datasheet](https://www.panjit.com.tw/upload/datasheet/P6SMB_SERIES.pdf). (Panjit range P6SMB or similar.)

**Reasoning**:

- That package type is common for various types of diodes. Measurements could help with a specific package identification (see datasheet page 1).
- `PJ` as part of the top marking - [Panjit Semiconductor](https://www.panjit.com.tw/en) perhaps?
- `2089` in the top marking - not mentioned on the datasheet above, but batch number, manufacturing location and/or date codes are typical explanations with other manufacturers.
- `Z1`/`Z2` component designators on the PCB are typically used for zener or TVS diodes. The component has no cathode marking, so it isn't a zener diode or other polarised diode, or a uni-directional TVS. However a bi-directional TVS would match a component like that in the photo, with no polarity marking.
- `DKZ` in the top marking - this matches a bi-directional TVS diode (therefore consistent with the point above) with an 8.55 V reverse stand-off voltage, from Panjit.

[image: Extract from page 2 of Panjit TVS datasheet linked above]

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the detailed description. This board is part of a heater controller (Haverland RC7W, 1100W). The programmer section does its job by sending a signal to this board to energize a relay (PN JQX-115F-I) when conditions are met (time of day and temperature). The relay does click but ever so slightly and the voltage at its terminals are around 7.5V DC. If I try a bench power supply and set it to 24V DC (the rated coil voltage), the click is much more pronounced and circuit does close as expected. Wish I could share pictures here. Thanks again.